# Use a pfx file for Certificate with VS2019 building a uwp app

Tags: c#, uwp, certificate, pfx

I'm using the ide Visual studio 2019. I create a uwp app and i want to install the app to a computer without publishing it to the playstore.

I created a pfx file (certificate). Now i want to integrate the pfx file in the app manifest for deploying purposes. With Visual Studio 2019 i can only show the certificate and view the data.

But i didn't find a way to browse the own pfx file.

Answer (score 0):

> Now i want to integrate the pfx file in the app manifest for deploying purposes

You could create your app package sideload file using Visual Studio.

**Steps for creating the sideload file:** Solution Explorer-> Right-click the project ->choose Store->Create App Packages -> select  I want to create packages for sideloading ->select Always for Generate app bundle >Create

**Steps for sideloading the app package:**  enable your device for development -> install the signing certificate to the Trusted People or Trusted Publishers Certification Authorities store ->double clicking the app package file(Windows 10 Anniversary Update or later.
)
You could see more details in document:[Create an app package upload file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps#create-an-app-package-upload-file) and [Sideload your app package on Windows 10 Anniversary Update or later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps#sideload-your-app-package-on-windows-10-anniversary-update-or-later)

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest way was to use VS2017 to create and assign the certificate.  VS2019 has removed the UI, though it appears they are considering bringing some or all of it back.

Further reading can be found on [this Visual Studio Developer Community discussion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/612872/create-test-certificate-option-missing-from-uwp-sd.html).